# Handling Right click on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, browser

I want to implement some manual functionality on right click on browser. How can I achieve that? Is there any plugin avail or any supporting js file available for that?

Comment: I removed the Java tag since it is not the way to go about this (fortunately).  BTW - why do you want to mess with the user's right click button?  That always p*sses me off, and I close that site and black-list it, even if the intent was honorable (which it usually **isn't**).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function ()
{
//code here
 return false;     // cancel default menu
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery something like

```
<div id="clickme">click</div>

$('#clickme').mousedown(function(event) {
    if(event.which==3) {
        alert('Right mouse button pressed');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKU4g/)

Comment: how can you tell if open new tab has been selected?